# boot from usb flash drive

Tags: linux-mint, boot, usb, windows, bootable

I have a Sony Vaio SV-E14A2M1E with Win 8.1; and I just created a bootable USB with Linux mint 17.1, but I can't boot from it. I've done a bit of research, but I'm not sure with what I've found.

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned you're using W8.1

Some things you might have a look at:

- SecureBoot
- AHCI
- General Problems / Usage for (Linux)/Ubuntu with newer hardware-> [UEFI Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: Welcome to the U&L site. This is not a forum, but a Q&A site. Please observe the  (read [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)): especially the "no distractions", and "no chit-chat" parts.

Comment: Probably Fast Boot needs to be turned off as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution it may fix your issue:
[bootable usb using cmd](https://coderwall.com/p/_u9jua/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick?p=1&q=author%3Aimad_bouhamidi)